# react context api state not persisting for synthetic onwheel event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mousewheel, react-context

I am trying to implement a onWheel triggered Nav for a carousel. The button nav works, while the onWheel triggers, but is somehow not accessing the initialized state of the context provider. Any insight would be appreciated. thank you.

context provider:

```
import CarouselContext from "../context/_carousel"

const CarouselProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [isInitialized, setIsInitialized] = useState(false)
  const [carouselLength, setCarouselLength] = useState(0)
  const [carouselPosition, setCarouselPosition] = useState(0)

  const initializeCarousel = length => {
    setCarouselLength(length)
    setIsInitialized(true)
    console.log(`carouselLength ${carouselLength}`)
  }

  const nextSlide = () => {
    if (carouselPosition === carouselLength) {
      setCarouselPosition(0)
    } else {
      setCarouselPosition(carouselPosition + 1)
    }
    console.log(`carouselPosition ${carouselPosition}`)
  }

  const previousSlide = () => {
    if (carouselPosition === 0) {
      setCarouselPosition(carouselLength)
    } else {
      setCarouselPosition(carouselPosition - 1)
    }
    console.log(`carouselPosition ${carouselPosition}`)
  }

  const state = { carouselLength, carouselPosition, isInitialized }
  const methods = { initializeCarousel, nextSlide, previousSlide }

  return (
    <CarouselContext.Provider value={[state, methods]}>
      {children}
    </CarouselContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default CarouselProvider
```

carousel structure:

```
return (
    <Page className="works">
      <CarouselProvider>
        <ScrollNav>
          <PreviousWorkButton />
          <Carousel>
            {works.map((work, index) => (
              <CarouselItem key={index}>
                <Work project={work} />
              </CarouselItem>
            ))}
          </Carousel>
          <NextWorkButton />
        </ScrollNav>
      </CarouselProvider>
    </Page>
  )
```

scroll Nav (which is consoling the events are triggered, but not showing the current position of the carousel or length)

```
const ScrollNav = ({ children }) => {
  const [, { nextSlide, previousSlide }] = useContext(CarouselContext)

  const delayedScroll = useCallback(
    debounce(e => changeNav(e), 500, { leading: true, trailing: false }),
    []
  )
  const changeNav = direction => {
    if (direction === 1) {
      nextSlide()
    }
    if (direction === -1) {
      previousSlide()
    }
  }
  const onWheel = e => {
    delayedScroll(e.deltaY)
  }

  return <div onWheel={onWheel}>{children}</div>
}
```

onclick button that triggers the same event with carousel position and length persisting

```
const NextWorkButton = () => {
  const [, { nextSlide }] = useContext(CarouselContext)

  const clicked = () => {
    nextSlide()
  }

  return (
    <div className="next-work-button">
      <button onClick={clicked}>
        <DownArrowSvg />
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

edited to add console.logs in the provider as is in my local copy

console logs on click event:

```
carouselPosition 1
carouselLength 5
```

console log on wheel event (the length does not print):

```
carouselPosition 0
```

Thanks to kumarmo2 I solved this by removing the debounce and calling the event directly. I made a very hacky debounce specific to the wheel event with a timer.
my solution:

```
const ScrollNav = ({ children }) => {
  const [, { nextSlide, previousSlide }] = useContext(CarouselContext)
  const [debounce, setDebounce] = useState(false)

  const timer = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setDebounce(false)
    }, 1000)
  }

  const changeNav = e => {
    let direction = e.deltaY
    if (debounce) {
      return
    } else if (direction >= 1) {
      setDebounce(true)
      timer()
      nextSlide()
      return
    } else if (direction <= -1) {
      setDebounce(true)
      timer()
      previousSlide()
      return
    }
  }

  return <div onWheel={changeNav}>{children}</div>
}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what is getting console logged and where are you putting those ?

Comment: @kumarmo2 I added what the log returns and the console.log calls in the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what is happening here is that, your `delayedScroll` is not getting updated because of `useCallback`. It "captures" the `changeNav` which in turn captures the `nextSlide`.

So nextSlide will be called, but since its references inside `delayedScroll` is not updated because of useCallback, you are facing the issue.

Can you try removing the `useCallback` and `debounce` once for `delayedScroll` ? and if it works, will introduce the debounce logic in the correct way.

Comment: I tried useMemo, but that didn't create a single instance of the event. This was the only way I could get debounce to fire the changeNav once.

Comment: can you try not to use useMemo and useCallback once ? that should atleast fix the issue. and if that works, will think of something for debounce. I wanna check first if removing these 2 solves the issue.

Comment: onWheel directly calling changeNav works just triggers multiple events. would this be a case to useRef to store the ref and then debounce?

Comment: thanks for the help I got it working with a new debouncing strategy

Comment: Awesome. Can you also post/edit the solution ?

Comment: added my solution, don't think it is the most elegant, but it works